# Trying to add a cocoapod framework to an extension in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to install or share a framework between my main app and my user notification extension. Here is my podfile.

```
def shared_pods

    pod 'Localize-Swift', '~> 1.7'
end

target 'EGY POST' do

  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Alamofire', '~>4.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'SCLAlertView'
  shared_pods


end

target 'PostOfficeNotification' do
    use_frameworks!

    shared_pods

end
```

I `pod install` and i get this error on the terminal:

> [!] The 'Pods-EGY POST' target has frameworks with conflicting names: localize_swift.

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround is to use `cocoapods` version 1.0.1